# onPostExecute() can't use MainActivity elements

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have `doInBackground()`. after function I want to change some `TextView` on `MainActivity`.
but When I trigger the function on main activity I got `NullPointerException` on `TextView` line.

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... arguments) {

    some code..

    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result!=null)
        new MainActivity().setScoreListUpdate(result);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public void setScoreListUpdate(String settings)
{
    String[] yeniscore = settings.split("\\|");

    if(yeniscore.length > 1)
    {
            birinci.setText(yeniscore[1]);  << NULLPOINTEREXC.
    }
}
```

Comment: In the onCreate method of MainActivity, do u get the TextView birinci by calling findViewById?

Comment: @Chunhui yes.. birinci = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birinci);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this gives a `NullPointerException` is that you create a new instance of `MainActivity` instead of working on your existing one.

What you need to do is pass a reference to your `Activity` to the `AsyncTask` and then call your method on that reference.

So in your `AsyncTask`-class you will have a variable:

```
private MainActivity myMainActivity;
```

Add a constructor to your `AsyncTask`-class:

```
public MyAsyncTaskClassName( MainActivity activity ) {
    myMainActivity = activity;
}
```

Then in `onPostExecute` you do:

```
myMainActivity.setScoreListUpdate(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MainActivity.this.setScoreListUpdate(result);
```

instead of

```
new MainActivity().setScoreListUpdate(result);
```

in yout `postExecute` method.

Also, TextView called `birinci` should be a field in your `MainActivity` class, not just a variable in the `onCreate` method for example.

**EDIT:** It works like this in my program. Check out the differences.

```
public class DeviceSettingsStatsActivity extends ListActivity {

    AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ListAdapter> task = null;
    ListAdapter listAdapter = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        task = new ComputeTask().execute();
    }

    protected void viewComputeResult(ListAdapter result) {
        setListAdapter(result);
    }

    private class ComputeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ListAdapter> {

        @Override
        protected ListAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // some stuff
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ListAdapter result) {
            DeviceSettingsStatsActivity.this.viewComputeResult(result);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but got "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: this works coz they are under same scope. but thanks for your time. really glad you guys :)